# I am using sqlite incorrectly in this kotlin class

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, kotlin-lateinit

I started learning kotlin recently, and I am trying to implement a database using SQLite. When I try using the functions the app crashes. I don't know how to find the error log so I have added the functions I made and where the functions are implemented. Thank you for your help.

```
package com.example.mrtayyab.sqlitedbkotlin

import android.content.ClipDescription
import android.content.ContentValues
import android.content.Context
import android.database.Cursor
import android.database.DatabaseUtils
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper

class DatabaseHelper(context: Context) : SQLiteOpenHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1) {


    companion object {

        val DATABASE_NAME = "passwords.db"
        val TABLE_NAME = "passwords_table"
        val COL_1 = "ID"
        val COL_2 = "DESCRIPTION"
        val COL_3 = "PASSWORD"
        val COL_4 = "DATE_TIME"
    }


    override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase) {

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $TABLE_NAME(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , DESCRIPTION  TEXT , PASSWORD TEXT , DATE_TIME INTEGER)")

    }

    override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $TABLE_NAME")
        onCreate(db)

    }

    fun insertData(description: String, password: String, date_time: String): Boolean? {
        val db = this.writableDatabase
        val cv = ContentValues()
        cv.put(COL_2, description)
        cv.put(COL_3, password)
        cv.put(COL_4, date_time)
        val res = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv)
        return !res.equals(-1)
    }

    fun getData(id: String, COL_NUM: String): Cursor {
        val column = arrayOf("$COL_NUM")
        val columnValue = arrayOf("$id")
        val db = this.writableDatabase
        return db.query("$TABLE_NAME", column, "$COL_1", columnValue, null, null, null )
    }

    fun getTableCount(): Long {
        val db = this.readableDatabase
        val count = DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, TABLE_NAME)

        return count
    }
}
```

Here is the code where it is implemented

```
package com.example.juliaojonah_hci_outcome2_v1

import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import android.widget.ScrollView
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.mrtayyab.sqlitedbkotlin.DatabaseHelper
import com.google.gson.Gson
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import java.text.DateFormat
import java.util.*
import kotlin.collections.ArrayList

class passwords : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var myDb: DatabaseHelper

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_passwords)



        val dateTime = Calendar.getInstance().time

        val dateFormatted = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM, DateFormat.MEDIUM).format(dateTime)

        val dateTextView : TextView = findViewById(R.id.textDate2) as TextView
        dateTextView.setText(dateFormatted)

        val recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.savedPasswords) as RecyclerView

        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false)

        val counter = myDb.getTableCount()

        val passwords = ArrayList<PasswordCluster>()

        if (counter > 0) {
            for (i in 1..counter) {
                var id = i
                var description = myDb.getData(id.toString(), "COL_2")
                var password = myDb.getData(id.toString(), "COL_3")
                var dateTime = myDb.getData(id.toString(), "COL_4")

                passwords.add(PasswordCluster(description.toString(), password.toString(), dateTime.toString()))
            }
        }

/*
        passwords.add(PasswordCluster("Amazon", "56,78,90,12", "Friday"))
        passwords.add(PasswordCluster("Amazon", "56,78,90,12", "Friday"))
        passwords.add(PasswordCluster("Amazon", "56,78,90,12", "Friday"))
        passwords.add(PasswordCluster("Amazon", "56,78,90,12", "Friday"))
        passwords.add(PasswordCluster("Amazon", "56,78,90,12", "Friday"))
*/
        val adapter = CustomAdapter(passwords)

        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
    }

    fun firstActivity(view: View){
        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

I use the save data function in this last piece of code and it doesn't crash, but I don't know if it is working correctly

```
package com.example.juliaojonah_hci_outcome2_v1

import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.text.TextUtils
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.example.mrtayyab.sqlitedbkotlin.DatabaseHelper
import com.google.gson.Gson
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import java.security.spec.PSSParameterSpec
import java.text.DateFormat
import java.util.*
import kotlin.random.Random


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var myDb: DatabaseHelper

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val dateTime = Calendar.getInstance().time

        val dateFormatted = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM, DateFormat.MEDIUM).format(dateTime)

        val dateTextView : TextView = findViewById(R.id.textDate) as TextView
        dateTextView.setText(dateFormatted)

        myDb = DatabaseHelper(this)
        }


    fun secondActivity(view: View){
        val intent = Intent(this, passwords::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }

    fun randomise(view: View){


        val passwordSet1 = Random.nextInt(0,99)
        val passwordSet2 = Random.nextInt(0,99)
        val passwordSet3 = Random.nextInt(0,99)
        val passwordSet4 = Random.nextInt(0,99)

        val editText1 = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.password1)
        editText1.setText(passwordSet1.toString())

        val editText2 = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.password2)
        editText2.setText(passwordSet2.toString())

        val editText3 = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.password3)
        editText3.setText(passwordSet3.toString())

        val editText4 = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.password4)
        editText4.setText(passwordSet4.toString())

    }



    fun save(view: View){
        var correct = true

        val description = descriptionName.text.toString().trim()
        val password = password1.text.toString().trim() + "-" + password2.text.toString().trim() + "-" + password3.text.toString().trim() + "-" + password4.text.toString().trim()
        val dateTime = Calendar.getInstance().time
        val dateFormatted = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM, DateFormat.MEDIUM).format(dateTime)

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(description)){
            descriptionName.error = "Enter description"
            correct = false
        }

        if (password == "---"){
            password1.error = "Enter password"
            password2.error = "Enter password"
            password3.error = "Enter password"
            password4.error = "Enter password"
            correct = false
        }


        var isInserted = myDb.insertData(description, password, dateFormatted)


        if (isInserted == true && correct == true){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Data Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            Toast.makeText(this, isInserted.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Data Not Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }




    }

}
```

Here is the error that first appears when I try to start up the password activity

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.juliaojonah_hci_outcome2_v1, PID: 20054
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.juliaojonah_hci_outcome2_v1/com.example.juliaojonah_hci_outcome2_v1.passwords}: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property myDb has not been initialized
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
     Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property myDb has not been initialized
        at com.example.juliaojonah_hci_outcome2_v1.passwords.onCreate(passwords.kt:42)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

This is what happens when I try to run the .getData function

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.juliaojonah_hci_outcome2_v1, PID: 20221
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.juliaojonah_hci_outcome2_v1/com.example.juliaojonah_hci_outcome2_v1.passwords}: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property myDb has not been initialized
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
     Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property myDb has not been initialized
        at com.example.juliaojonah_hci_outcome2_v1.passwords.onCreate(passwords.kt:51)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

Comment: post your error log.

Comment: *I don't know how to find the error log so I have added the functions I made and where the functions are implemented.* see [Debug your app](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug)

Comment: Thank you for you comment MikeT, I added the error log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I try using the functions the app crashes.

`lateinit property myDb has not been initialized` is saying that you need to initialise myDB. that is you need to include :-

```
myDB = DatabaseHelper(this)
```

- before accessing/using myDB, perhaps straight after `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`

> I am using sqlite incorrectly in this kotlin class
>   You aren't too far away but you appear to misunderstand queries and for Android Cursors.
>   In short you are querying the database in a loop when a single query can return all of that information and you can then loop through the result the Cursor.

Here's some of the issues.

In the **getData** function you should be using `"${COL_1}=?"` for the 3rd paramter to the call to **query** as this parameter is the **WHERE** clause less the WHERE keyword. You are effectively saying `SELECT whatever_column_is_passed FROM passwords_table WHERE x;`

- x will be the value passed (1 then 2 then 3 ....). As the where clause expects either true or false and that 0 is false and other numbers are positive all rows will be returned.

However, you then have a few issues in regard to processing (not processing it) the **Cursor** returned from the **getData**.

First you assume that the number of rows in the table  `val counter = myDb.getTableCount()` is going to equate to the rows returned and that the id's will be numbered 1,2,3....... This may initially be the case but if a row is deleted or if an insert fails then the sequence may not be monotonically increasing.

When going through the loop you are trying to assign a Cursor to a String e.g. `var description = myDb.getData(id.toString(), "COL_2")` will result in **description** being a Cursor. To get around the issue of trying to build a PasswordCluster not liking a Cursor you have used the **Cursor**'s **toString** method which will result in the default object **toString** method being used, which returns details about the Cursos not the expected value (description, password or datetime).

## Suggested Fix

It appears that you want to get a list of PasswordCluster's into **passwords** (*`val passwords = ArrayList<PasswordCluster>()`*) fro the RecyclerView.

I'd suggest that you should have a function in the **DatabaseHelper** class that retruns the list of all passwords as an ArrayList e.g.

```
fun getListOfAllPasswordClusters(): ArrayList<PasswordCluster> {
    val rv = ArrayList<PasswordCluster>()
    val db = this.writableDatabase
    val csr = db.query(TABLE_NAME,null /* ALL columns */,null,null,null,null,null)
    //return db.query("$TABLE_NAME", column, "$COL_1", columnValue, null, null, null )
    while (csr.moveToNext()) {
        rv.add(
            PasswordCluster(
                csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_2)),
                csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_3)),
                csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_4))
            )
        )
        /* NOTE ideally you should also store the id in PasswordCluster
            So assuming a constructor that takes
                Long /* id */
                ,String /* description */
                ,String /* password */
                ,String /* date_time */

                E.G.
        rv.add(
            PasswordCluster(
                csr.getLong(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_1)),
                csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_2)),
                csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_3)),
                csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_4))
            )
        )
        */
    }
    csr.close()
    return rv
}
```

- Note I strongly suggest ensuring that a PasswordCluster object can store the **id** as this value offers the most efficient means to access a specific row (e.g. to update/delete/extract a single row).

  - You will often see Int for id this will probably work in most cases but the id is actually a Long (64 bit signed integer). As such I suggest always considering it as a Long.
- Coding **AUTOINCREMENT** is very likely not required and is also inefficient. Perhaps read [SQLite Autoincrement](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html).

  - It appears that many think that it's needed for getting an automatically generated sequential **id**, it's not **INTEGER PRIMARY KEY** on it's own does that.

Then you could have :-

```
class passwords : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var myDb: DatabaseHelper

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_passwords)    
        val dateTime = Calendar.getInstance().time   
        val dateFormatted = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM, DateFormat.MEDIUM).format(dateTime)   
        val dateTextView : TextView = findViewById(R.id.textDate2) as TextView
        dateTextView.setText(dateFormatted)    
        val recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.savedPasswords) as RecyclerView    
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false)    
        val passwords = getListOfAllPasswordClusters()
        val adapter = CustomAdapter(passwords)    
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
    }

    fun firstActivity(view: View){
        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

## Working example

This is an example based solely upon adding the suggested **getListOfAllPasswordClusters()** *(with the commented out part replacing the `rv.add(.........)` code so the **id** is retrieved)* function and using the following code in the activity :-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var myDB: DatabaseHelper

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        myDB = DatabaseHelper(this)
        addSomeDataIfNone()

        val passwords = myDB.getListOfAllPasswordClusters()
        for (p: PasswordCluster in passwords) {
            Log.d("PASSWORDCLUSTER","ID=${p.id} Description=${p.description} password=${p.password} datetime=${p.date_time}")
        }
    }

    fun addSomeDataIfNone() {
        if (DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(myDB.writableDatabase,DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME) > 0) return
        myDB.insertData("Test1","password1","2019-12-01")
        myDB.insertData("Test2","password2","2019-12-02")
        myDB.insertData("Test3","password3","2019-12-03")
    }
}
```

- Note that for convenience the activity is MainActiviy rather than **passwords**

The runs and results in :-

```
2019-12-01 07:59:58.289 D/PASSWORDCLUSTER: ID=1 Description=Test1 password=password1 datetime=2019-12-01
2019-12-01 07:59:58.289 D/PASSWORDCLUSTER: ID=2 Description=Test2 password=password2 datetime=2019-12-02
2019-12-01 07:59:58.289 D/PASSWORDCLUSTER: ID=3 Description=Test3 password=password3 datetime=2019-12-03
```

Comment: When I try to initialise the myDB it just appears red and says unresolved reference. I removed the lateinit var myDB but then the myDB.getdata() would go red

Comment: @NyusenKyusai a working example (less UI) has been added. At a guess your issue is that you are not reading/considering the entire answer.

Comment: Thank you for you help. I got it all to work, even in the recyclerView

Answer (score 1):

In short, `class passwords` needs to initialize `myDB = DatabaseHelper(this)` within it's `onCreate()` method. You can't just initialize it somewhere and then assume it would be initialized somewhere else. When the new `Activity` has no initialized handle, there won't be any handle to use. Look closely, only one of the two `Activity` initializes the handle.